# if exist folder rmdir folder && mkdir folder will not execute any command after that &&

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2012

What is the syntax that would allow me to delete folder and the create it, regardless of it prior (in)existence?

```
if exist folder rmdir folder && mkdir folder
```

Will NOT work. Neither replacing `&&` with `&`, `||`, `|`...

Which is proper syntax then?

OS: Windows 2012
Shell: cmd.exe*

PS I could accept PS based answers as long as two conditions are met. 1) It have to start from cmd.exe 2) It have to give meaningufull errors to cmd standard output if there are any encountered (like lack of permissions).

Comment: Brackets. Tell CMD what is what in your command. `(if exist folder rmdir folder) & (mkdir folder)` does it I think.

Comment: `rmdir folder & mkdir folder` you don't need to test (which uses battery power for an extra disk access and is slow) I assume that folder is empty or the syntax of rmdir is wrong see `rmdir /?` If folder in not empty you use `rd /s /q folder`

Comment: Both solutions worked like a charm! Even when folder is actually symlink ;) Please turn that into answer so I can accept it, and also explain why single `&` and not double one from code in question (for completeness sake)

Comment: double && also work for me, only thing different is bracket, which are must to differentiate for checking existence for only 1st command

Comment: @Bhavjot if (exists folder) rmdir folder && ... ?

Comment: This works: (if exist folder rmdir folder) && mkdir folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `rmdir` without the `/S` switch I assume the folder of interest is empty, so why removing and recreating it? You could simply create it and suppress the error message in case it already exists, like:

```
mkdir "folder" 2> nul
```

This variant maintains all folder attributes and the owner, of course.

---

If you insist on removing and recreating the folder, use this:

```
rmdir "folder" 2> nul & mkdir "folder"
```

This variant destroys all folder attributes and the owner.

---

In case the folder is *not* guaranteed to be empty, you need the `/S` switch for `rmdir`; also the `/Q` is useful to avoid being prompted to really remove the folder, like:

```
rmdir /S /Q "folder" & mkdir "folder"
```

Comment: Ouch. Well folder in question is actually symlink  created as "mklink /D". So it can always be removed with rmdir. But rmdir will complain if there is nothing to remove.

Comment: That is what the `2> nul` part is for -- to suppress the error of `rmdir` in case...